# How can I check if a user is a bot using their id?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I know how to check if a message is sent by a bot using `if(message.author.bot)` but I want to know if their is a way to find out if they are a bot using their id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the user then simply check their `bot` property.

```
const userID = 'id-here';

// client = your Discord Client Object
client.users.fetch(userID).then(user => {
   console.log(user.bot);
   // Will return a boolean
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As far as I know, and from reading the docs, there is no difference between how user and bot IDs are created.

Comment: The user is asking how to check if a user is a bot given their id

Comment: Did not think of it that way